# bootstrap social media buttons, only show on mobile version??

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

This is my code, the social media links dont appear in desktop view. how can i change this so that they appear on any screen size?

```
<footer>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <span class="copyright">Copyright &copy; Your Website 2014</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <ul class="list-inline social-buttons">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <ul class="list-inline quicklinks">
                        <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Terms of Use</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

Comment: There is no reason why it shouldnt appear on larger screens with this code. The only thing hiding will be css. What does the class `social-buttons` and `fa` do?

Comment: social-buttons just specifies how they will appear on the page, but has no mention of screen sizes, and the fa is a class related to the social media logos? so confused... @haxtbh